# Window.Opener in Blackberry Browser

Tags: javascript, mobile, blackberry, cross-browser

It seems the blackberry browser(5.0) doesn't seem to like javascript window.opener function. Google didn't help much.

We have an existing website , which fills the parent window form fields with data from the child window. We are trying to mimic the same functionality in our Blackberry website. But, the window.opener function returns null in blackberry browser

I have the following questions

1) Is it a known issue?

2) If it is a known issue , is it an issue on all the OS versions of Blackberry ?

3) If BB doesn't support window.opener , what are other options to pass data from child window to parent window?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The browser in BB OS5.0 has poor support for javascript so that might be the reason for it failing. Try to load the same feature in BB OS 6.0. The device simulators should give you a good impression of how it will load on an actual device.

Please clarify whether you are referring to a mobile website or a mobile app made with html, css & javascript (PhoneGap or WebWorks)

Comment: I was referring to mobile website using Jquery Mobile. It seems an issue with BB OS 5.0 .  The functionality works just fine on BB OS 6 device.